# What's the spectrum of $A = \frac{1}{i} \frac{d}{dx}$, if $\text{dom } A = \left\{ u \in L^2 \left[a,b\right] \: : \: u(a) = 0 \right\}$?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory, spectral-theory

We are in $L^2 \left[a,b\right]$ space. We define our operator $A$ as follows: $$A = \frac{1}{i} \frac{d}{dx}$$ The domain of our operator $A$ is equal to $\text{dom } A = \left\{ u \in L^2 \left[a,b\right] \: : \: u(a) = 0 \right\}$

Question: What is the spectrum of our operator $A$?

**My attempt**

We need to find those eigenvalues ($\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$) for which $(A - \lambda I)$ is not invertible. In order to find them, we instead try to find those for which $(A - \lambda I)$ is actually invertible. So we get: $$(A - \lambda I) \cdot u(x) = v(x)$$ We set $v(x) = 1$, so we have $$(\frac{1}{i} \frac{d}{dx} - \lambda) \cdot u(x) = 1$$ This will get us: $$\frac{1}{i} \frac{du}{dx} - \lambda \cdot u = 1$$ which is $$\frac{1}{i} u'(x) - \lambda u(x) = 1$$ This gives us the solution: $$u(x) = -\frac{1}{\lambda} + C e^{i \lambda x}$$ We also know, that $u(a) = 0$. So we get: $$0= u(a) = -\frac{1}{\lambda} + C e^{i \lambda a}$$ which is true for $C = \frac{1}{\lambda e^{i \lambda a}}$.

Ultimatelly, we get: $$u(x) = -\frac{1}{\lambda} + \frac{1}{\lambda e^{i \lambda a}} e^{i \lambda x}$$ Now the question is: Is $u(x) \in L^2 \left[a,b\right]$? Or in other words: For which $\lambda$ is $u(x) \in L^2 \left[a,b\right]$?

That's with what I'm struggling with, especially because we have the imaginary unit here. We defined that a function $u(x) \in L^2 \left[a,b\right]$, if $u(x)$ is measurable and $$\int_a^b |u(x)|^2 dx < \infty$$

So how can I show (for which $\lambda$) our $u(x) \in L^2 \left[a,b\right]$?

Maybe I should elaborate why it is important to find those $\lambda$: Those lambdas for which $u(x) \notin L^2 \left[a,b\right]$ are my spectrum, because then for those lambdas, $(A - \lambda I)$ wouldn't be invertible in the domain of $A$.

I already apologize if there are some misunderstandings here, we just started the topic of Spectral Theory and our Prof gave us this as an exercise.

Comment: I fail to see how $(A-\lambda I) u(x)=1$ implies that $(A-\lambda I)$ is invertible. Could you clarify? For instance, loose the condition that $u(x)=0$ so the domain is larger, then $(A-1)(-1))=1$, but clearly $e^{ix}$ is an eigenvector of $A-1$ so that it is not invertible. This shows that the domain must play an important role there.

Comment: That is how my Professor argues. It's like if you take $a \in \mathbb{R}$, then $a \cdot a^{-1}  = 1$. So, if you can find such a function $u(x)$, that $(A - \lambda I) u(x) = 1$, then you've found the reciprocal of $(A - \lambda I)$. Here, the additional condition would be - as far as I've understood it - to check if that $u(x)$ which we're able to find is an element of $L_2$. I have already taken into account in the construction of my $u(x)$ that $u(a)= 0$. But to show that what I've got is also $L_2$, i need to prove that $\int_a^b |u(x)|^2dx < \infty$ (for which $\lambda$ this is the case)

Comment: Also, what exactly is the domain of $A$, because note that it doesn't make sense to apply it to non differentiable functions. Also, not all functions of $L^2$ are derivatives (I think, for instance the characteristic function of the rationals), so that $A-\lambda I$ won't be surjective. If you require at least $C^1$ then the image $A-\lambda I$ will be continuous functions, so that you have no chance of $A-\lambda I$ being surjective.

Comment: This argument is for this specific case? Because it is most certainly false in general.

Comment: The example we did before that during lecture was with the same conditions but for $u \in \mathcal{C}^1$, and not $L_2$. And here, the spectrum was just the empty set, but I didn't understand why exactly though.

Comment: $\lambda$ is complex, not real. We define the spectrum as the set of $\lambda$ for which $(A - \lambda I)$ is not invertible.

Comment: What is the definition of spectrum you are using? Because if is that $A-\lambda I$ is not a bijection, then if we require $u \in C^1$, then every complex number is in the spectrum, since $(A-\lambda I )u$ is continuous and since continuous function form a proper subspace of $L^2$, so that it is impossible for $A-\lambda I$ to be surjective.

Comment: Just as I told you, the spectrum of an operator $A$ is the set of all values (complex) $\lambda$ for which $(A - \lambda I)$ is not invertible.

Comment: That's what I'm saying as well. If a functions $u(x)$ is $C^1$ then so is $-iu'(x)-\lambda u(x)$ for any $\lambda \in \mathbb C$, so that the image of $A-\lambda I$ is a proper subset of $L^2$, so it is not surjective and cannot be invertible, so that $specA=\mathbb C$

Comment: Why isn't it surjective?

Comment: There are functions in $L^2$ which aren't continuous.

Comment: But how does this connect to surjectivity? Are we talking about the surjectivity of $u(x)$?

Comment: $(A-\lambda I): C^1 \rightarrow L^2$, so for it to be surjective we must have that $(A-\lambda I)(C^1) = L^2$, but we know that  $(A-\lambda I)(C^1) \subset C^0$, which is a proper subspace of $L^2$.

Comment: What does "proper subspace" mean? Also, why $(A - \lambda I) : C^1 \rightarrow L^2$?

Comment: A proper subspace is a subspace which isn't the whole space.For the second question, if you want to define an operator you must define it domain and codomain as well as its action.  Typically, we define an unbounded operator, such as this one, on a dense subspace and its domain is always the whole space. In this I chose to have as its domain $C^1$, and showed that if we consider this domain then every number is the spectrum of $A$.

Comment: But why is the operator's codomain $L^2$?

Comment: In a Hilbert space $H$ you define an operator to be a linear map $A : DomA \subset H \rightarrow H$. Of course, every operator can be as an operator into its image, but that's not good, because then every operator would be surjetive by definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resolvent equation is found by solving
$$
          (A-\lambda I)f=g
$$
which translates to solving the following ODE for $f$:
$$
    \frac{1}{i}f'-\lambda f = g,\;\; f(a)=0.
$$
That is,
$$
             f'-i\lambda f=ig \\
             e^{-i\lambda x}f'(x)-i\lambda e^{-i\lambda x}f(x)=ie^{-i\lambda x}g(x) \\
           (e^{-i\lambda x}f(x))'=ie^{-i\lambda x}g(x)
$$
Integrating over $[a,x]$ gives
$$
          e^{-i\lambda x}f(x)=i\int_a^xe^{-i\lambda x'}g(x')dx' \\
      f(x)=i\int_a^x e^{i\lambda(x-x')}g(x')dx'
$$
So the resolvent operator $R(\lambda)$ exists for all $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ and
$$
     R(\lambda)g= i\int_a^x e^{i\lambda(x-x')}g(x')dx'.
$$
To see that $R(\lambda)$ is a bounded linear operator for all $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$, you can apply the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
\begin{align}
    |(R(\lambda)g)(x)|^2 &\le \int_a^x|e^{i\lambda(x-x')}|^2dx'\int_a^x|g(x')|^2dx' \\
  & \le\int_a^x e^{-2\Im\lambda(x-x')}dx'\|g\|^2 \\
  \|R(\lambda)g\|^2 &\le\left(\int_a^b\int_a^x e^{-2\Im\lambda(x-x')}dx'dx\right)\|g\|^2.
\end{align}
(This proves that $R(\lambda)$ is a bounded operator on $L^2[a,b]$ for all $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$.) Therefore the spectrum of $A$ is $\sigma(A)=\emptyset$.

Comment: How do we check if $R(\lambda)$ is bounded on $L^2 \left[a,b\right]$ for all $\lambda$?

Comment: @anon : Integrate $\int_a^b |R(\lambda)g|^2dx$, and use Cauchy-Schwarz in order to bound this by a constant times $\int_a^b |g(x)'|^2dx'$.

Comment: Why would $\int_a^b |R(\lambda)|^2 dx = C$? Or am I missing something here? Because we want to show that $\int_a^b |R(\lambda) g|^2 dx \le (\int_a^b |R(\lambda)|^2 dx) (\int_a^b |g|^2 dx) = C \cdot \int_a^b |g|^2 dx < \infty$?

Comment: @anon : I put in the complete calculation of boundedness for the resolvent operator. Hope this helps.

Comment: Where exactly do we use the fact, that $f(a) = 0$?

Comment: @anon : On the line with the first integration.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you very much for your help!